# How to calculate the minimum of parametric curves?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

[image]

I just want the outer profile of the graph (bottom). I tried, but it's not working.

```
mean,std=0.03,0.00666
s=np.random.normal(mean,std,8)
r=0.2
v=2*np.pi*600/60
f=20/60
for i in s:   
        t=np.arange(0,10,0.001) 
        k=r+i
        c=v/k
        m=np.sqrt((k**2-(k-0.01)**2)/k)
        j=np.arcsin(m)
        x=k*(np.sin((c*t)+j))+f*t
        y=k*(np.cos((c*t)+j))
        ax.set_xlim([1,2])
        ax.set_ylim([y.min()-0.02,-0.1]) #less than zero profile
        ax.set_xlabel('x (µm)')
        ax.set_ylabel('y (µm)')
        ax.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])

        ax.plot(x,y)
```

The algorithm is like: for each x there should be only one y-value for and that y will be minimum.

Comment: numpy has a minimum function that can operate along specific axes. i would put all of your data into a single numpy and take the minimum only the appropriate axis

Comment: i tried appending the x and y values in list and they are coming in array. Like here we have 8 points so 8 arrays ..don't know how should i utilize it .

Comment: if your question, you say you "tried but it's not working". What exactly did you try?

Comment: i tried gathering all the values of y for a single x and tried to get the minimum ..but i am not getting the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the minimum, we need `y` as a function of `x`.  As the x-values go back and forth, we need to chop up the arrays into chunks where `x` goes up and other chunks where it goes down.

We create two arrays to hold the result. One is `xm` to hold the x-values of the minimum. It is a `linspace` of the x-range we are interested in. `ym` will hold the corresponding y-values.  Each chunk will first be mapped onto the `xm` range (via `np.interp`) and the `ym` will be constantly updated to contain the minimum.

To experiment with the code, it helps to simplify the example.  The code below only draws two curves with simplified formulas.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

high = 2  # some value higher than the expected minimum
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xm = np.linspace(0, 2, 500)  # the x-range for the minimum
ym = high  # ym will be the array of minimum values

for i in range(2):
    t = np.linspace(0, 20, 2000)
    x = np.sin(t) + 0.1 * t + i * 0.1
    y = np.cos(t) + 0.02 * t - i * 0.1
    ax.plot(x, y, color='b')

    ind0 = 0
    reversed = False
    while ind0 < len(x):
        ind1 = ind0 + 1
        if reversed:
            while ind1 < len(x) and x[ind1] <= x[ind1 - 1]:
                ind1 += 1
            ym = np.minimum(ym, np.interp(xm, x[ind0:ind1][::-1], y[ind0:ind1][::-1], left=high, right=high))
        else:
            while ind1 < len(x) and x[ind1] >= x[ind1 - 1]:
                ind1 += 1
            ym = np.minimum(ym, np.interp(xm, x[ind0:ind1], y[ind0:ind1], left=high, right=high))
        ind0 = ind1
        reversed = not reversed

ax.plot(xm, ym, color='m', lw=5, alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

[image: minimum of parametric curve]

Comment: I want 3D profile for the same . How should i proceed with that ?

Comment: Probably xm then needs to be a  2D grid and ym then corresponding values using interp2d. It could be extremely slow.

Comment: Can we append xm ym into a list and then apply np.meshgrid and pass a z value to get the 3D profile ?

Comment: You probably need a 2D grid (created by something like `np.meshgrid`)

Comment: Yes that's what i am saying. We can append the value xm and ym into a list ,right ?

Comment: No, xm and ym are 1D. You need a 2D version of xm and a 2D version of ym. It's much more complicated than just appending, you need to create 2D grids.

Comment: Last question. I just wanna know the xm part .can i take np.linspace(0,1,1000)  or any another interval ?

Comment: For the 1D case you can use `np.linspace(0,1,1000)` or other lengths for the interval. The higher, the more precise, but also slower. 1000 would already be quite high compared to the pixels visible on a screen.

Comment: How do i convert the xm and ym into 2D array ? I want a 3D plot for the same for the same ? can you help in that ? I have 3rd dimension of 50 units.

Comment: Did you try `np.meshgrid`? Maybe you can post a new question, with some simplified data so somebody else can chime in? You also need to think about how to display it. Maybe as a surface in 3D but with the original data hidden (or very transparent).

Comment: yes ..i want a surface plot. The thing is y in the figure should be my Z direction and i having width of  any constant value. How should i divide this width ? can i use linspace ?Also, I don't know what 2D dimension should i give to the Z(ym) to have a surface plot.

Comment: I have added a new question ..can you take a look ?